# why can we factor a polynomial using its solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, factoring

Can someone please explain why we are able to factor an $n$ degree polynomial function using only it roots?

What I mean is this:

Lets say we have a function defined like so:
$$f(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 +\dots$$
It can supposedly be factored like so:
$$f(x) = a(x−p)(x−q)(x−r)\dots$$
Where $p, q, r$ etc. are the solutions of the function being equal to $0$.
Is there a simple proof for why this is valid, and where does the coefficient $a$ in the factored form come from? (I don't want some lame answer for $a$ like :"if $a$ wasn't there the factored form wouldn't equal the original form"

Comment: Read about Bezout's theorem.

Comment: Familiar with the [Fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)?

Comment: Have you looked at the Factor Theorem?

Comment: "*and where does the coefficient $a$ in the factored form come from?*"  It is the same $a$ as in $f(x)=ax^n+bx^{n-1}+\dots$

Comment: As for a "*simple proof*"... the fundamental theorem of algebra is one of the classic results in an undergraduate course in Algebra (*abstract/modern algebra, a course on group theory, ring theory, etc... not just a pre-calculus how to perform arithmetic with letters*).  To fully understand and appreciate it, you'll probably want to get a lot more under your belt with regards to Groups, Rings, Euclidean Domains, Unique Factorization Domains, etc... Any decent Algebra textbook should cover this in plenty of detail.  Else, quotient-remainder or degrees might not make full sense.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for telling me this, I really would like to understand why this works since it has bugged me ever since I learned it in school, I hate it when a concept is taught without any proper insight as to why it works. Its always taught like "it just works".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider your polynomial $p(x)$, with zeros $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n$. Take:

$\begin{align*}
   p(x)
     &= q(x) (x - z_i) + r(x)
\end{align*}$

(plain polynomial division, $q$ is quotient, $r$ remainder). You know that the degree of $r$ must be less than the degree of $x - z_i$, i.e., it is a constant. Now:

$\begin{align*}
   p(z_i)
     &= q(z_i) \cdot 0 + r(z_i)
\end{align*}$

so you see that $r(z_i) = 0$, but $r(x)$ is a constant. Thus you conclude:

$\begin{align*}
   p(x)
      &= q(x) (x - z_i) \\
      &\vdots \\
      &= a (x - z_1) (x - z_2) \dotsm (x - z_n)
\end{align*}$

The $a$ is just the leading coefficient of $p(x)$, the coefficient of the highest power of $x$ (if you multiply out the rest, the leading coefficient is 1, a *monic* polynomial).